# using defined constant (from Makefile) to form a part of a variable name in C

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Is it possible to use a defined constant to form a part of a variable name in C? The constant is defined by the Makefile.(actually I want to pass it by make argument as shown below)
For example, I want to define a number `NUM` and declare a variable using it.

```
#define NUM 5
/* I want to declare as below
int var5 
using defined constant `NUM` above
*/
```

I tried

```
int var ## NUM;
```

but the ## concatenation is only for preprocessing macro manipulation and doesn't work.
Actually the constant `NUM` is passed in from Makefile (by CFLAGS += -DNUM=5) in mycase.
How can I do this?

### ADD1

According to Shachar Shemesh's answer below, I tried this.

=== test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define compound_id(name1, name2) name1##name2
int compound_id(mynum, NUM);

main()
{
mynum5 = 5;
printf("NUM = %d\n", NUM);
printf("mynum5 = %d\n", mynum5);
```

== Makefile

```
ifeq ($(NUM),5)
CFLAGS+=-DNUM=$(NUM)
endif
```

== command

```
make test NUM=5
```

I get the following result :

```
ckim@stph45:/tmp] make test NUM=5
cc -DNUM=5    test.c   -o test
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:8: error: 'mynum5' undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:8: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:8: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

What is wrong?

### ADD 2

: I tried this too,(no Makefile, just run `make test`)
=== test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM 5
#define mynum(X) (int mynum##X;)
mynum(NUM)

main()
{
printf("NUM = %d\n", NUM);
mynum5 = 5;
printf("mynum5 = %d\n", mynum5);

}
```

and get this error :

```
ckim@stph45:/tmp] make test
cc     test.c   -o test
test.c:5: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'int'
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: What about `-Dvar=var5`?

Comment: I want to use the variable as a text, not a variable. ??

Comment: The error message points to the line `mynum5 = 5`, which I think should be `int mynum5 = 5`.

Comment: @MaxLybbert I tried to declare the variable using `mynum(NUM)`

Comment: I see it now.  OK, when I tried with `compound_id(mynum, 5)`, things worked.  The problem is that even when `NUM` is `#define`d, `compound_id(mynum, NUM)` turns into `mynumNUM`.  Sadly, I'm not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you can use is multilevel macro expansion.  Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* This emulates the constant that comes from your makefile. */
#define NUM 5
/* This allows VAR2() to be called with the value of NUM (5)
   instead of just the string "NUM". */
#define VAR(x) VAR2(x)
/* This actually concatenates 'var' and '5' to be 'var5'. */
#define VAR2(x) var##x
/* This allows you to stringify your variable name.
   Again, we're using multilevel macro expansion so we get the
   desired output string "var5" and not "VAR(NUM)". */
#define MACRO_STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* Declare your variable */
    int VAR(NUM);

    /* Assign a value to your variable */
    VAR(NUM) = 7;

    /* Print your variable name and its value */
    printf(MACRO_STRINGIFY(VAR(NUM)) " = %d\n", VAR(NUM));

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
var5 = 7
```

And in case you're confused why that is the output, here's what `main()` looks like after preprocessing (i.e. all macro expansion is complete) but before compiling:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int var5;

    var5 = 7;

    printf("var5" " = %d\n", var5);

    return 0;
}
```

You can see exactly what your macros turn into by preprocessing your source file.  For example, if you are using `gcc` and your source file is `source.c` you could preprocess it like this, with the results being stored in `source.i`:

```
# gcc -E source.c -o source.i
```

Comment: Wow, that was the answer I was looking for. So we use two level expansion to use the expanded string as a text! interesting..

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a macro to use concatenation of the preprocessor. However, to ensure that your `NUM` is also preprocessed, you have to use two levels of macros, for example:

```
#define CONCAT_IMPL(LHS, RHS) LHS ## RHS
#define CONCAT(LHS, RHS) CONCAT_IMPL(LHS, RHS)
```

See [Argument Prescan](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan).

Comment: Now I reallized what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define compound_id(name1, name2) name1##name2

int compound_id(var, NUM);
```

Comment: @Shachar Shemesh  Hello, Thanks. I tried your answer but doesn't work. Please see my updated question and could you give me a more elaborate answer?

Comment: In your edit to the question, all the above is commented out - is that actually what you tried?

Comment: @Useless sorry, I removed the comment bars. The (previously) commented lines cause dcompile errors I showed.